# Trying to return value upon Mouseup C#

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm trying to accomplish what I thought would be somewhat straight forward, but apparently isn't.

What I'd like to accomplish is as follows.  The user presses a button in a toolbar, this allows the state of the UI to change.  Now that the state has changed when the user clicks mouse-down they can create a box on the screen by dragging the mouse.  Upon the mouse-up I want to return the x,y coord.

So basically something like this

```
protected void MyUI_MouseDown(object inSender , MouseEventArgs inArgs)
{
  switch(myState)
  {
    case CreateBox:
      Rectangle rect = DrawBox();
  }
}

public Rectangle DrawBox()
{
   myDrawFlag = true;
}

private MyUI_MouseMove(object inSender , MouseEventArgs inArgs)
{
  if(myDrawFlag)
  {
    DrawBox(inArgs.X , inArgs.Y);
  } 
}
```

Basically, I'm not sure how to get from point A to point C.  The mouse down changes the state of the UI and lets me draw on the screen via the Mouse Move - but I want to return the value upon the Mouse UP.

I know I'm doing something wrong - could someone tell me what?

Edit 1:  Yes, there is nothing in DrawBox().  Basically my question is how do I have that method not return UNTIL, I get the mouse-up event?

Edit 2: I am tracking the mouse movement events.  As the mouse moves I am updating the start X,Y and the new endpoint X,Y.  I still think I'm not asking this question correctly.

I don't want return DrawBox() until the mouse-up event.  Mouse-Down should just notify the UI it can draw a box on the screen.  Mouse-Move (which I'm using) updates the coordinates.  And then Mouse-Up should tell the UI it can't draw anymore and ONLY THEN should DrawBox() return with the points.

Comment: Your DrawBox() method is defined to return a Rectangle but doesn't. Is there some code missing?

Comment: My question is how do I get it to return something.  When I enter my DrawBox method, I set a flag so now when I drag the mouse, I can draw on the screen.  Basically, I don't want to exit DrawBox until the mouse-up.  But I'm not sure how to do that....

It's a threading issue I think, but I dunno

Comment: In an event-driven system, you don't do such a thing.  You track mouse down, mouse move and mouse up events and keep the processing within each one small and efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea to wait inside the MouseDown method until die MouseUp event is fired is not the way to go. You have to think event driven. Better create/save your final object in the MouseUp method.

```
protected void MyUI_MouseDown(object inSender, MouseEventArgs inArgs)
{
    switch(myState)
    {
        case CreateBox:
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(inArgs.X, inArgs.Y, 0, 0);
            break;
    }
} 

protected void MyUI_MouseUp(object inSender, MouseEventArgs inArgs)
{
    rect.Width = inArgs.X - rect.X;
    rect.Height = inArgs.Y - rect.Y;
    // now save/draw your object
}
```

Comment: The problem is I have a control within a control.  The toolbar item is pressed....that code is expecting a rectangle to be returned so it can do some additional processing.  the Mouse-Move is just doing some basic GDI drawing on the screen...

It's basically

BaseControl:DrawBox - > MyControl (which has the Mouse-Down/Mouse-Move/Mouse-Up)

So that BaseControl doesn't care how that box is drawn...it just wants that rectangle back

Comment: Give your inner control a method StartDrawing and an event DrawingFinished. The outer control (with the toolbar) registers for this event. If the toolbutton is clicked, call StartDrawing, on the method registered for the event, process the results of the drawing ...

Answer (score 0):

You can store your points in a struct and then fill up the struct in the MouseUp event, and reuse it where you wish.

```
struct coords
{
   int x;
   int y;
}

coords my_coords;
protected void MyGui_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
{

    my_coords.x = args.x;
    my_coords.y = args.y;
}

//here you can use my_coords to what you need...
```

Comment: Getting the poitns on the Mouse-UP isn't the problem, maybe I'm not asking the question the right way. 

I don't want to return DrawBox until after I get those points

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the MouseUp event.  The MouseMove event you are handling will fire every pixel change in distance that the mouse moves so you are in effect calling the DrawBox(int, int) method hundreds of times.  If you handle the MouseUp event instead you will get the coordinates when the mouse button is released.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see it, you have 3 states:

**Normal**, which doesn require any explanation.

**DesignMode**, When the button in he toolbar is clicked.

**DrawingBox**, When you are actually drawing the box

Now you want the following transition:

Normal -> DesigMode -> OnDrawingBox -> AfterDrawingBox.

This can implemented using a state machine or an enum. With the enum, your code will be something like this:

```
        enum DrawBoxState { Normal, DesignMode, DrawingBox }

    DrawBoxState _currentState = DrawBoxState.Normal;
    Point _startPoint;
    Point _endPoint;

    void OnToolbarButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (_currentState)
        {
            case DrawBoxState.Normal:
                _currentState = DrawBoxState.DesignMode;
                break;
            default:
                _currentState = DrawBoxState.Normal;
                break;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (_currentState)
        {
            case DrawBoxState.DesignMode:
                {
                    _currentState = DrawBoxState.OnDrawingBox;
                    _startPoint = e.Location; // not sure if this is right
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (_currentState)
        {
            case DrawBoxState.DrawingBox:
                {
                    _currentState = DrawBoxState.Normal;
                    _endPoint = e.Location;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now you can simply, raise an event every time the state changes, and adept changes on that event. e.g. if state changes to normal, check if startPoint and endPoint have been set and therefore do something with the value's.